# NameError: name 'record' is not defined. Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, chat, server, messaging

I've been trying everything I can to run this code, but I can't figure out what the issue is. It's a server/client chat program in python 3. The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nate/Desktop/soc_chat/server_soc.py", line 48,<module>
    handler = ClientHandler(client, record)
NameError: name 'record' is not defined
```

I'm not sure how I can fix this issue. Any help would be great. I'm on ubuntu, with python 3 installed. I've tried running the code as 'python3 myFile.py' in the terminal instead of 'python myFile.py' also to make sure it's not trying to run it as python 2. As I said, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code(server side):

```
from socket import *
from codecs import decode
from chatrecord import ChatRecord
from threading import Thread
from time import ctime

class ClientHandler(Thread):

    def __init__(self, client, record):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self._client = client
        self._record = record

    def run(self):
        self._client.send(bytes('Welcome', CODE))
        self._name = decode(self._client.recv(BUFSIZE), CODE)
        self._client.send(bytes(str(self._record), CODE))
        while True:
            message = decode(self._client.recv(BUFSIZE), CODE)
            if not message:
                print('Client disconnected')
                self._client.close()
                break
            else:
                message = self._name + '' + \
                          ctime() + '\n' + message
                self._record.add(message)
                self._client.send(bytes(str(self._record), CODE))


HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 5000
BUFSIZE = 1024
ADDRESS = (HOST, PORT)
CODE = 'ascii'
server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDRESS)
server.listen(5)

while True:
    print('Waiting for connection...')
    client, address = server.accept()
    print('...connected from:', address)
    handler = ClientHandler(client, record)
    handler.start()
```

Code(Client Side):

```
from socket import *
from codecs import decode

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 5000
BUFSIZE = 1024
ADDRESS = (HOST, PORT)
CODE = 'ascii'
server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
server.connect(ADDRESS)
print(decode(server.recv(BUFSIZE), CODE))
name = input('Enter your name: ')
server.send(bytes(name, CODE))

while True:
    record = decode(server.recv(BUFSIZE), CODE)
    if not record:
        print('server disconnected')
        break
        print(record)
        message = input('> ')
    if not message:
        print('Server disconnected')
        break
        server.send(bytes(message, CODE))
server.close()
```

Code(chatrecord.py)

```
class ChatRecord(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def add(self, s):
        self.data.appent(s)

    def __str__(self):
        if len(self.data) == 0:
            return 'No messages yet!'
        else:
            return '\n'.join(self.data)
```

Comment: So what do you expect `record` to be? You did not define it when calling `ClientHandler`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say you forgot the following line:

```
record = ChatRecord()
```

You import the class but never use it in the server-side code.

Note that you misspelled `list.append()` in the `ChatRecord.add()` method:

```
def add(self, s):
    self.data.appent(s)
    #              ^
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I had figured out that record was not set to ChatRecord, but I didn't catch the misspelled 'append.' It's telling me that 'message' is not defined on the client side now though. I have it set to an input if there is no message currently from the server side, but everything I've tried just ends up making it disconnect.

Comment: @user3629818: if `record` is empty on the server, then `message` is not set either..